# How is one to interpret OBrien's wisdom in 1984?

Tags: 1984

In 1984, we see that O'Brien is a human being, and he is obviously an intelligent quick-witted individual who has a rich understanding of human psychology and philosophy.  There are occasions, however, when his wisdom seems to transcend just above average sharpness of mind and sensitivity, and seems to enter the realm of psychic abilities / super-aware mysticism.

*Some Examples:*

> 'I told you, Winston,’ he said, ‘that metaphysics is not your strong point. The word you are trying to think of is solipsism.'

---

> ‘There are a couple of minutes before you need go,’ said O’Brien. ‘We
> shall meet again — if we do meet again ——’
>
> Winston looked up at him.
>
> ‘In the place where there is no darkness?’ he said hesitantly.
>
> O’Brien
> nodded without appearance of surprise. ‘In the place where there is no
> darkness,’ he said, as though he had recognized the allusion.’

---

> "Do you remember, the moment of panic that used to occur in your
> dreams? There was a wall of blackness in front of you, and a roaring
> sound in your ears. There was something terrible on the other side of
> the wall. You knew that you knew what it was, but you dared not drag
> it into the open. It was the rats that were on the other side of the
> wall."

I can imagine various explanations for O'Brien having that knowledge/understanding, but I wanted to know if anyone knows how Orwell intended us to understand it.  I mean, it is one thing to know the essence of one's dreams, but it is quite another to reach into the dream; recall a specific instant; and then to explain to the dreamer what he, the dreamer, was not seeing.

How does Orwell intend us to interpret this power?

Comment: The Supreme Leader is wise.

Comment: @Valorum - I looked at that question, and I disagree that it is a duplicate.  I am not suggesting that there were mind-reading devices in 1984 - in fact, if there were, most of the novel would be pointless.  Why spy on people when you can read their minds?  It would change the context of the novel in a most unappealing way.  I **do not** think that this is how Orwell intended us to interpret this.

Comment: @user1167442 - Although "psychic abilities" doesn't necessarily equal "mind-reading machine", I think the implication is quite similar.

Comment: This should be reopened.  See my previous comment.  This question still looks good to me 5 years later.